# variable PWM frequency and duty cycle in real time

Tags: pic, adc, pwm

My project is based on a strict time management and precise event timing

for that I need to vary the PWM frequency and duty cycle in real time with two potentiometres.

I've succeded to vary the duty cycle with one potentiometre using a pic18f2550 but I couldn't neither add another analog input for the second potentiometre nor vary the frequency.

I also may need up to 4 PWM signals which will be identical but delayed between eitch other, for this I know that the 18f family has only two CCP modules, so could you please tell me which pic can do the job.

the code below is for a simple duty cycle variation.

Any help is strongly appreciated

thank you all in advance

```
#include <xc.h>
#include "PWM_config.h"

#include <pic18f2550.h>

void init_ADC (void)
{
ADCON1=0b00001110; //setting voltage reference and AN0 as analog input 
ADCON0bits.CHS=0b0000; //setting channel 0
ADCON2=0b10011101; /* 16Tosc conversion clock, 6Tad acquisition time, ADC Result Right Justified */
}

int doADC0(void)
{
int result; 
ADCON0bits.ADON=1; //turning on ADC
__delay_us (5); // acquisition delay of 4.6 us 
ADCON0bits.GODONE=1; //start conversion 
while (ADCON0bits.GODONE==1);
result=ADRES*0.0977517; 
return result; 
}


void init_PWM1 (unsigned char period)
{
TRISCbits.RC2=0; 

/*CCP PWM mode*/
CCP1CONbits.CCP1M=0b1100; //CCP1 to PWM mode
CCP1CONbits.DC1B=0b00; 

/*timer2 configuration*/
PR2=(period*312500)-1; //avec Fosc=20MHz
T2CON=0x02; //set prescaler to 16
TMR2ON=1; 
}

void PWM_setDC (unsigned int pourcentage_DC)
{
unsigned int DC=(10.23*pourcentage_DC); 
CCPR1L = DC>>2; // PWM duty cycle - first 8-bits (MSb)
CCP1CON |= ((DC<<4)&0x30); // PWM duty cycle - last 2-bits (LSb) in CCP1CON 5,4 bits
}
void main (void)
{
TRISAbits.RA0=1; 
init_ADC(); 
init_PWM1(0.002); //setting the period to 2ms 
while (1)
{
if (doADC0()<1) {PWM_setDC(0); PORTCbits.RC2=0; } 
else PWM_setDC(doADC0());
}
}
```

Comment: I have to say the formatting is awful.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with a 16f1788 pic, has 4 programmable switch mode controllers and PSMC GUI tool available from Microchip. It saved me hours of programming and debugging. The tool makes pwm configuration very easy.

Comment: The problem is that this configuration is fixed for the hole program. But for my case I need an instant variation of the frequency.

Comment: what would be the range of frequency you look for ?

Comment: from 10Hz to 100Hz